# Multiple write_dynamic_frame calls in AWS Glue write asynchronously?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

We are writing scripts in aws glue (pyspark) manipulating and extracting data from xml files; for each xml file we have a single glue job writing to multiple different tables in our RDS database. The first table written is our parent table that contains all the foreign keys necessary for writing the additional tables to our database. However, we have observed inconsistent glue job failures due to a foreign key error. These foreign key errors typically resolve on a rerun of the job.

From our analysis of cloudwatch logs, it appears if we invoke multiple write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf calls within a single glue job that all batches within a given write are not guaranteed to complete before the next one starts. Is this a known behavior of glue? Are there options to influence this?

Any thoughts or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried separating this logic into two jobs and leverage Glue triggers to start another job execution bases on the parent job status?

Comment: @Prabhakar Reddy We have considered that as a possible workaround to this issue (albeit using a step function rather than glue triggers), but would like to avoid doing so if possible to avoid complicating our workflow. Additionally we would like to understand this behavior we are seeing.

Comment: It looks like your job is making parallel connections to JDBC because there are multiple number of files. Have you tried writing to the later table first and then to the actual table?

Comment: @Prabhakar Reddy Each job is for a single file (although we do have multiple jobs running in parallel). And we have to write to the actual table first as this table contains the foreign keys for the other tables.